# Open new file while keeping the focus on the the current buffer

Tags: buffers

It is possible to open a new file with  :edit or :tabnew but without jumping to that new buffer ?

Comment: no, but you can make a custom command, that will jump back from after opening a new window/tabpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `:badd {fname}` is what you are looking for. It just adds a new buffer to the buffer list without switching to it.

See `:help badd`.

I don't think there is something similar for tabs.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this! Way better than the custom command solution! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a command to do this. Not to worry though - you can define your own commands to do it!

For edit, you might want to use something like this to open the file then immediately switch to the previous buffer.

`command -nargs=1 Bgedit edit <args> | bprevious`

Which you can call with `:Bgedit filename`.

**Explanation:**

`command` - Create a new user-defined command

`-nargs=1` - With one argument (the filename)

`Bgedit` - Name of the command (user-defined commands have to start with capital letters).

What comes next is what you will run when :Bgedit gets called:

`edit <args>` - open the file

`|` - Used in vim to chain two commands together, like a semicolon in bash

`bprevious` - switch to the previous buffer.

For tabnew, you can do the same thing, but using `tabprevious`

`command -nargs=1 Tabbgedit tabnew <args> | tabprevious`

You would put these two lines in your .vimrc.

Comment: For windows, you could do `(v)split | wincmd p`